# HTML5 Video does not play in any browser

Tags: html, video, browser, mp4, codec

I have a video with the following information
[It is MP4 video with H264 codec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt2w7.jpg)

However, using the following code:

```
<video width="500" height="440" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">

Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The video does not play and looks like this when I render it [Rendered Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW9nL.jpg)

I have checked the codec is H264 and I have tried other browsers and none of them work. I can see the video using VLC. I am using the localhost and I am working on windows 10. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

The information using mediainfo is as follows:

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/mp42)
File size                                : 16.3 MiB
Duration                                 : 2 min 41 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 846 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2020-04-04 23:03:29
Tagged date                              : UTC 2020-04-04 23:03:29

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L5.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 5 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 5 frames
Format settings, GOP                     : N=1
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2 min 41 s
Bit rate                                 : 791 kb/s
Width                                    : 3 840 pixels
Height                                   : 2 060 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.004
Stream size                              : 15.2 MiB (93%)
Title                                    : H.264/AVC video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2020-04-04 23:03:29
Tagged date                              : UTC 2020-04-04 23:03:29
Codec configuration box                  : avcC
```

Comment: `I have checked the codec is H264` h264 alone does not guarantee it can play. for example yuv444 will not play. Please run ffprobe, or media info on the file and post the results. Or post a link to the file.

Comment: @szatmary thank you. I have already provided the link to video information in my post. If you please click on "it is MP4 with H264 codec".

Comment: That image (In the future, please don't post images of text, post the text) is missing many many details of the file and codec parameters. I need the file, or the the full ffprobe or media format output (as text, not a picture)

Comment: @szatmary I just run the mediainfo on it and I posted the complete output here.